# How to load wxXmlDocument from std::istream?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I would like to load a `wxXmlDocument` from a `std::istream` but unfortunately, there's no `Load(std::istream&)` member function, even if `wxWidget` is compiled using standard input/output streams.

For what it's worth, I'm using wxWidgets 3.1.0 on macOS.

Comment: Not sure why this had been downvoted, the question looks perfectly good to me -- upvoted it back to 0, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there are alternatives but, since `wxXmlDocument` provides a `Load(wxInputStream&)`, a solution can be to define an adapter like this one:

```cpp
class myStdInputStreamAdapter : public wxInputStream {
public:
  myStdInputStreamAdapter(std::istream &s): stream{s} {}

protected:
  std::istream &stream;

  virtual size_t OnSysRead(void *buffer, size_t bufsize) {
    std::streamsize size = 0;

    stream.peek();

    if (stream.fail() || stream.bad()) {
      m_lasterror = wxSTREAM_READ_ERROR;
    } else if (stream.eof()) {
      m_lasterror = wxSTREAM_EOF;
    } else {
      size = stream.readsome(static_cast<std::istream::char_type *>(buffer),
                             bufsize);
    }

    return size;
  }
};
```

And then use it to load the xml:

```
void f(std::istream &istream) {
    wxXmlDocument xml;

    myStdInputStreamAdapter inputStreamAdapter(istream);

    xml.Load(inputStreamAdapter);
}
```

Comment: And the answer looks good to me too, so, again, it would be interesting to know why had it been downvoted.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the `std::istream::read` will `setstate(failbit|eofbit)` when it encounter `eof`. In some cases, for instance if you use `myStdInputStreamAdapter` to load a `wxXmlDocument` during `wxDocument::LoadObject`, the stream will be then in fail state and you get a `wxLogError` unless you clear it. Is there a better way?

Comment: I fixed it by calling `std::istream::peak` and `std::istream::readsome`; now I also set `m_lasterror` according to the `wxInputStream::OnSysRead` [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_input_stream.html#a8ebacd18964a4b169a62ad9190cab4d5)